# capturing pointer events in overlapping g-elements in a svg

Tags: javascript, events, d3.js, svg, mouseover

I am adding 2 g-elements to the same SVG like

```
var charts = svg1.append("g")
                .attr("class","charts")
                .attr("id","charts")
                .style("opacity",0);
var bubbles = svg1.append("g")
                .attr("id","bubble");  

var bubbleId = document.getElementById( 'bubble' );
var backId = document.getElementById( 'back' );
var chartId = document.getElementById( 'charts' );
bubbleId.addEventListener( 'click', chartSVG );
backId.addEventListener( 'click', bubbleSVG );


function bubbleSVG(){
    bubbleId.style.opacity = 1;
    chartId.style.opacity = 0;
    bubbleId.style.z_index = 100;
    chartId.style.z_index = 10;            
}

function chartSVG(){
    bubbleId.style.opacity = 0;
    chartId.style.opacity = 1;
    bubbleId.style.z_index = 10;
    chartId.style.z_index = 100;  

}
```

I position them to overlap each other and I toggle between their opacities(bubbleId,chartId) using another div element (backId)

Bubble and chart svgs have bubble and circle layout respectively.

I have the following issue now..

If I do a mouseover event capture on the chartId, for circles that overlap with bubbles, the event DOES NOT get captured on the page with higher z-index, instead all the time the event get captured on the bubbleId....

any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this by clicking on objects (circle and rectangle)

```js
var width = 400, height = 300;
function bubbleSVG(){
    bubbleId.style.display = 'unset'; 
    chartId.style.display = 'none';
    }

function chartSVG(){
    chartId.style.display = 'unset'; 
    bubbleId.style.display = 'none'; 

}
function toggleSVG(){
if(bubbleId.style.display == 'none'){
 bubbleSVG()
}else{chartSVG()}
}
var svg1 = d3.select("body")
 .append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height);

var back = svg1.append("g")
                .attr("id","back")
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x","0") 
                .attr("y","0")
                .attr("width",width)
                .attr("height",height)
                .attr("fill","yellow");  
var charts = svg1.append("g")
                .attr("class","charts")
                .attr("id","charts")
                .style("opacity",1)
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x","50") 
                .attr("y","50")
                .attr("width","50")
                .attr("height","10")
                .attr("stroke","black")
                .attr("stroke-width","3")
                .attr("fill","blue");
var bubbles = svg1.append("g")
                .attr("id","bubble")
                .append("circle")
                .attr("cx","50") 
                .attr("cy","50")
                .attr("r","40")
                .attr("stroke","black")
                .attr("stroke-width","3")
                .attr("fill","red");  

var bubbleId = document.getElementById( 'bubble' );
var backId = document.getElementById( 'back' );
var chartId = document.getElementById( 'charts' );
bubbleId.addEventListener( 'click', chartSVG );
chartId.addEventListener( 'click', bubbleSVG );
backId.addEventListener( 'click', toggleSVG );


bubbleSVG();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: shall try it..thanks..so u are using display style  option for unset-ing and toggling...shall try it

Answer (score 1):

z-index will not work in svg.

One option would be to use `pointer-events` none to disable mouse events on a group read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

```
 function bubbleSVG(){
        bubbleId.style.opacity = 1;
        chartId.style.opacity = 0;
        d3.select(bubbleId).style("pointer-events", "auto");
        d3.select(chartId).style("pointer-events", "none");
    }

function chartSVG(){
    bubbleId.style.opacity = 0;
    chartId.style.opacity = 1;
    d3.select(bubbleId).style("pointer-events", "none");
    d3.select(chartId).style("pointer-events", "auto");
;
}
```